# Running a Spring Boot app with Quartz

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have this Spring Boot app. using Quartz (a richly featured, open source job scheduling library that can be integrated within virtually any Java application ) to execute a Job the 10th day of the month

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class IberiaUtilsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(IberiaUtilsApplication.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    ..
}
}
```

and inside the config package:

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobDetail sampleJobDetail() {
        return JobBuilder.newJob(MonthlyIberiaMetrics.class).withIdentity("iberiaJob")
                .usingJobData("iberiaMetrics", "fleet").storeDurably().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Trigger sampleJobTrigger() {

        return newTrigger()
                .forJob(sampleJobDetail())
                .withIdentity("iberiaTrigger")
                .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 10 10 * ?"))
                .build();               

    }
}
```

I run the app. from the command line, using `mvn spring-boot:run` but it seems that the Quartz is not initialised:

```
...
    017-10-31 15:11  [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2017-10-31 15:11  [main] WARN  c.z.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  o.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.0 created.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.0) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
      Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
      NOT STARTED.
      Currently in standby mode.
      Number of jobs executed: 0
      Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
      Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.0
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.quartz.AutowireCapableBeanJobFactory@64ea8964
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
    2017-10-31 15:12  [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@589ebb: startup date [Tue Oct 31 15:11:56 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2017-10-31 15:12  [Thread-3] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    MacBook-Pro-de-lopes:iberiaUtils lopes$
```

I also tried changing the expression to `0 * * * * ?` (every minute) with the same result

and also created this other class with the same result:

```
public class ScheduledTasks1 {


    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
    public void reportCurrentTime() {

        System.out.println("The time is now {}" +
                dateFormat.format(new Date()));

    }
}
```

for your information, I have another similar application without `Quartz properties` and its working fine:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class IberiaReservationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IberiaReservationsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetail sampleJobDetail() {
        return JobBuilder.newJob(CheckDBJobExecution.class).withIdentity("sampleJob")
                .usingJobData("name", "World").storeDurably().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Trigger sampleJobTrigger() {
            return newTrigger()
                .forJob(sampleJobDetail())
                .withIdentity("sampleTrigger")
                .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/2 8-17 * * ?"))
                .build();               

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are following the recipe for integrating quartz with spring-boot properly.  You are never scheduling that trigger/job, for example,

Comment: That's a normal info. just change the cron to `0 * * * * ?` to see if your job is running. (Every minute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Springs own scheduler, it's easy to configure and I've always found it to work well.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing various configuration for Quartz here like

1. Quartz properties
2. SchedulerFactoryBean

Follow below examples for complete implementation:

1. https://chynten.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/quartz-with-databse-and-spring-4/
2. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule